SpEL for @RequestParam - required with condition
Is it possible to make the @RequestParam required to be checked against SpEL based on a certain condition? I want one of my fields to become mandatory if a specific @RequestParam  is not provided.
For example:
@GetMapping("/example")
public String exampleHandler(@RequestParam(required = false) String pageId,
                             @RequestParam(required = "#pageId == null") String otherParam,
                             @RequestParam(required = "#pageId == null") String otherParam2)
) {
    return "PageId: " + pageId + ", OtherParam: " + otherParam;
}

but I can't do like my example because
error Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'boolean'
If pageId is provided, all other parameters should be ignored. If pageId is null, then all other parameters should be mandatory.

Why not do it in the body of the method? I mean - all required = false, and then verify conditions in the body directly.

I'm thinking about such an option, just when there are many request parameters, very ugly code is obtained, so I'm looking for alternatives

You could pass HttpServletRequest as argument and then write a function to extract the parameters directly from the request

but anyway you have to add a similar "ugly" code to handle cases: if pageId !+ null... In any cases...

Nope, it's a REST API logic so I want keep in controller for easy readability, swagger etc.
